# Where can i find the deployed ear in WAS 8.5 from eclipse?

Tags: spring, websphere

I am able to deploy the spring MVC application through Run As on project to the WAS 8.5 server.
but couldn't find where the ear file is placed.
Also observed that application deployed through eclipse is not showing up in console.

Any suggestions would really appreciated.

Comment: I presume the app url is not coming up as well.

Answer (score 1):

The app may still be in your Eclipse workspace, if WebSphere is local, Eclipse only copies a "pointer" to your app into WebSphere.   If you really want it copied over, under the "servers" view there is a setting run on server / run from workspace that you can change.  I like to run on server, it takes a little longer to copy over but it's closer to the way the app will really be run.  Eclipse likes to be in control, I've noticed if you use both Eclipse and the console, one or the other can get into an incorrect state.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the app url is not coming up as well.
Did you check below?
[What needs to be done to add a project to a Websphere Server in Eclipse juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828005/what-needs-to-be-done-to-add-a-project-to-a-websphere-server-in-eclipse-juno/24991639)
[STS 3.4.0 with Websphere 8.5.5.0 don't deploy my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287655/sts-3-4-0-with-websphere-8-5-5-0-dont-deploy-my-application)